# Question on closures and closed sets

Tags: real-analysis

Lets say we have two balls of the same radius, but one is open and the other is closed.
How to prove that the closure of the open ball is contained in the closed ball?

I know that the closure of a set is the smallest closed set containing that set, but how do I connect it with my closed ball that is the closed "version" of the open one... 
If the closure was the closed ball itself it would still work, but I do have to show for a more general form... 
Also, at what cases could the closure be equal to the closed ball...?

P.S. sorry for any lack of clarity, haven't had much sleep in the last 42 hours.

Comment: Dude, go sleep...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) the closed ball is closed and contains the open ball.

2) the closure of the open ball is the smallest (which means: is contained in every other subset of the topological space) satisfying both conditions: being closed and containing the open ball.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: You can try to show this by noting that there is no closed set $B'$ such that $B_1\subset B' \subset B_2$, $B-'$ is the open ball and $B_2$ is the closed one (you must assume that both of them have the same center).

Another strategy is looking at the set $B_2-B_1$.

Comment: Should we consider the metric?

Comment: it's just a metric space. no specifications...

Comment: Yes @Tao, it's a real analisys question after all... using metrics makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be the open ball; and $B'$ is the closed ball with the same radius, and center as the first one. And let $\overline{B}$ be the closure of $B$.

Note that $\overline{B}$ is the *smallest* closed set that contains $B$.

Moreover, $B'$ is closed, and contains $B$ (Do you see why? You can obtain $B$ by taking $B'$, and shred off it's boundary). So the *smallest* property of $\overline{B}$ tells us that $\overline{B} \subset B'$.

Comment: what case would it be equal to B?

Comment: They are, in fact equal. The closure of $B$ is $\overline{B} = B \cup \delta B$, where $\delta B$ is the set of limit points (or, you can imagine it as the boundary) of $B$, and of course $B' = B \cup \delta B = \overline{B}$. Here $\delta B$ is the set of points, of which distance from the center is exactly $r$, that is the "boundary" of $B$. Get some sleep man.